# adfuller test received ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I have some numbers stored in a variable called "constant"

[image]

When I try to test the mean-reversion by using

```
cadf = ts.adfuller(constant)
```

I received ValueError: too many values to unpack.

How can I solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `constant` 2d array? `adfuller()` accepts 1d array only.

Comment: @ElisByberi Thanks!

I used cadf = ts.adfuller(constant[0]), then its ok.

Comment: Find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100441/i-am-trying-to-run-dickey-fuller-test-in-statsmodels-in-python-but-getting-error?rq=1

Comment: That's answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100441/i-am-trying-to-run-dickey-fuller-test-in-statsmodels-in-python-but-getting-error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`adfuller()` function accepts only 1d array of time series 
so first convert it using:

```
data1 = data.iloc[:,0].values
```